# Fuel Cell Chart - Anode, Cathode, Electrolyte

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrolysis, oxidation-state, fuel

Can someone please check my table to make sure I have the correct information. I am especially unsure of the parts highlighted in yellow:

[image]

Comment: Have tried to search in google because all this is available on wikipedia.

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure if I have the correct information.

Comment: http://artsandsciences.virginia.edu/cchf/research/fuelcells.html